# Physijs Handle Collisions of Meshes in Groups

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs

I'm trying to identify when a collision occurs between two meshes I've created. The problem is that one of the meshes is nested into a bunch of `THREE.Object3D` objects, so the collision isn't being detected. When I add another object directly to the scene ( `scene.add(myObject)` ), the collisions between that object and the other object at the top of the scene are recognized. However, there is still no collision detected between the mesh inside of the `THREE.Object3D`.

Is there a way to have Physijs detect collisions between meshes which are a direct child of the `scene` object, and meshes which are a child of a `THREE.Object3D`, which is a parent to the child?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I ended up writing a basic collision detection engine which identifies collisions between lines and planes. I'm not sure how useful this would be for average applications, though. If you'd like to see, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I actually solved your initial problem by making sure that the parents of all the children are Physijs objects. https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Compound-Shapes

Comment: Funny - I tried that and it didn't work for me. Oh well - glad you found your solution!

Comment: Had to fiddle around with it a bit. They should definitely make the docs more clear in that regard.